# How can I handle an object about the teacher's placement?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a problem placing the lecturer in the class they have previously registered. I need to handle an object to get the result. This object has the form (with the number of classes, the number of teacher per class is not fixed and the number of classes equals the number of teachers):

```
{
     Class1: {Teacher1: '333333', Teacher2: '000000', Teacher3: '444444'},
     Class2: {Teacher1: '000000', Teacher2: '111111', Teacher3: '444444'},
     Class3: {Teacher1: '444444', Teacher2: '555555'},
     Class4: {Teacher1: '222222', Teacher2: '000000'},
     Class5: {Teacher1: '333333'},
     Class6: {Teacher1: '111111', Teacher2: '000000'}
}
```

There are a few rules to produce results:

- 1 teacher/ 1 class
- If a class has only 1 registered teacher, that teacher will be selected
- If a teacher only registers for one class, that instructor will be selected for that class
- If there are more than one possible case, choose at random
- If not possible, return false, else return object result

Expected result:

```
{
    Class1: '000000',
    Class2: '444444',
    Class3: '555555',
    Class4: '222222',
    Class5: '333333',
    Class6: '111111',
}
```

or

```
{
    Class1: '444444',
    Class2: '000000',
    Class3: '555555',
    Class4: '222222',
    Class5: '333333',
    Class6: '111111',
}
```

or

```
{
    Class1: '444444',
    Class2: '111111',
    Class3: '555555',
    Class4: '222222',
    Class5: '333333',
    Class6: '000000',
}
```

I don't know much about algorithms, is there a simple way to solve them? Thank if you read it!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried recursion and looping for this object, but haven't found a way to solve them yet

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried so far? Even if it doesn’t work, at least we can get an idea of where you’re at.